# Loop in Camunda

Tags: camunda

Is it possible to use Loop in Camunda or it is only visualization mark?

[loop option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEzvG.png)

I'm trying to replace this option, because it seems that if the diagram has several loops made through gateways, it will make it harder to read.

[gatevay option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJxUe.png)

Answer (score 1):

The loop marker is not supported by Camunda.
See here:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.20/reference/bpmn20/tasks/task-markers/#loops